# Question about generic method

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to make the following method to a generic method and got struck.

```
public static MyObject[] getObjectFromList(List<MyObject> inputList) {
        if (inputList != null && inputList.size() > 0) {
            return inputList.toArray(new MyObject[inputList.size()]);
        } else {
            inputList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
            MyObject obj = new MyObject();
            inputList.add(obj);
            return inputList.toArray(new MyObject[inputList.size()]);
        }
    }
```

and have the other method which is similar but it's MyObject2

```
public static MyObject2[] getObjectFromList(List<MyObject2> inputList) {
            if (inputList != null && inputList.size() > 0) {
                return inputList.toArray(new MyObject2[inputList.size()]);
            } else {
                inputList = new ArrayList<MyObject2>();
                MyObject2 obj = new MyObject2();
                inputList.add(obj);
                return inputList.toArray(new MyObject2[inputList.size()]);
            }
        }
```

How do I make this as a single method which takes any object(myobject,myobject2) list and 
returns an array ?

Comment: Just a question: why do you add a new object if the list is empty?

I'd just let the method return an array of length 0, in which case you can just use inputList.toArray(new MyObject[0]) (which creates a new array according to the list length and returns that).

Comment: @Thomas, just to eliminate null's (calling this method for contract-first web service)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it without changing method signature due to type erasure. If you can pass a `Class` object identifying the desired type you can do something like this:

```
public static <T> T[] getObjectFromList(List<? extends T> inputList, Class<T> c) {
    if (inputList == null || inputList.isEmpty()) {
        inputList = new ArrayList<T>();
        T obj = null;
        try {
            obj = c.newInstance();
        } (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Instantiation failed", ex);
        }
        inputList.add(obj);
    }             
    return inputList.toArray(Array.newInstance(c, inputList.size()));            
}
```

Comment: +1. I'm really suspicious of this requirement for "at least one object" though. But that's the way to do it.

Comment: one suggestion - `inputList.isEmpty()`

Comment: This indeed works. But is it accepted by standards to send class as parameter ?

Comment: @TuxGeek: If you really need this behaviour it's inevitable, and yes, it's a widely used workaround.

Comment: Thanks @axtavt. Accepting this as my answer. Thx @Bozho. Your inputs are also very helpful.

Comment: Aren't there any checked exceptions in there (as it turns out, checked exception here are a jolly good thing).

Answer (score 3):

There is a method for that already - `List.toArray()`.

However, generics in Java do not allow for creating array of generic types (generics are lost at runtime, so `E[] e = new E[5]` is *not possible*. So if you want to have an array of a specific type, rather than `Object[]` (which t he above method returns), use:

```
MyObject[] array = list.toArray(new MyObject[list.size()]);
```

Having "at least one object in the list" is a requirement I would very much question. It does not sound right. If you are really certain you want it, axtavt has provided the correct method.

Comment: Thanks @Bozho. Agree, But I need to return at least one object in the array. I guess we can't make it as generic in that case.

Comment: @TuxGeek you can, if your object has a default contructor. see the answer by @axtavt . But I would be really suspicious about this requirement. The object that you create will be just a placeholder without any meaning.

Comment: Yes, It does have an constructor. Could you plz guide me how to make ?

Comment: @TuxGeek see the answer of @axtavt

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    System.out.println(list);
    Integer[] array = listToArray(list);
    for(Integer i : array) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static <T> T[] listToArray(List<T> list) {
    return listToArray(list, (Class<T>) list.get(0).getClass());
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static <T> T[] listToArray(List<T> list, Class<T> clazz) {
    return list.toArray((T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, 0));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the method a generic type parameter:

```
public <T> T[] getObjectFromList(List<T> c);
```

Or with objects of type MyObjectInterface:

```
public <T extends MyObjectInterface> T[] getObjectFromList(List<T> c);
```